# how to setup up Gas Price POA network

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, poa, binance-smart-chain, geth-clique

I have setup POA Network with clique, 5 Node with Public RPC, everything working fine, but i would like to setup Gas Fee to 25 GWEI automatically Metamask pick this estimation, by Default POA has 1 GWEI, how where where i can setup this on my Geth Node,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geth's command line https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options has the option

```
--miner.gasprice value  Minimum gas price for mining a transaction (default: 1000000000)
```

You have to set that command line in every validator.